# Significato di "in carnicino" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Su una ruota stesa per terra era seduto un ragazzo, **in carnicino** e calzoni strappati, una sola bretella, e teneva una gamba divaricata, scostata in un modo innaturale.

Ho cercato il termine "carnicino" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "in carnicino" nella frase sopra citata. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Tanto per buttarla lì: è possibile che sia “camicino” affetto da un problema di OCR? È per caso un ebook?

Comment: Non poteva avere semplicemente avere un abito color carne?

Comment: Per curiosità: cercando su Google Books “in carnicino e calzoni strappati” apparentemente ci sono vari risultati ma poi in tutti quelli che ho guardato, andando a vedere la scansione vera e propria, si legge “camicino”.

Comment: Hai ragione, @DaG! Sulla mia versione ebook appare "in carnicino", ma ho potuto controllare su una versione cartacea che avevo letto molti anni fa e là c'è scritto "in camicino". Quindi si tratta di un refuso della versione ebook.

Comment: Adesso penso che la domanda si dovrebbe chiudere perché è "off-topic" (si tratta di un problema di tipografia e non di lingua).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not about Italian language, but about typography.

Comment: @DaG: E cosa sarebbe un camicino? Una sorta di grembiule?

Comment: @Charo: A orecchio direi una specie di maglietta o canottiera, come uno dei significati di [camiciola](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/camiciola).

Comment: @DaG:  Mmmm... Non so se dovrei chiederlo in un'altra domanda.

Comment: @DaG: Vedo che si trova sul [dizionario Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/camicino.html). Forse era qualche sorta di canottiera o un corpetto.

Comment: Giusto, @Charo, e ho guardato anche sullo Zingarelli, che dà una definizione simile: “1 dim. di camicia | piccola camicia per neonati; 2 davantino femminile di tela fine che un tempo si metteva sotto il vestito e copriva le spalle e il petto; 3 corpetto maschile di raso, usato un tempo”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tratta semplicemente di un refuso della versione ebook del romanzo (ISBN 9788858409596). Ho potuto contrastare con una versione cartacea nella quale appare "in camicino" invece di "in carnicino".

Answer (score 0):

Per [carnicino](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/carnicino/) la Treccani riporta:

> **carnicino** agg. [der. di carne]. – Del colore roseo della carnagione:
>   tessuto c., seta carnicina.

Nel contesto da te citato carnicino sottintende che l’indumento indossato era di un colore simile alla carne.