# Significato dell'espressione "a testo"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, adverbs

**Riassunto:**

Siccome questo post con tutti gli aggiornamenti che ho fatto è diventato molto lungo, ne faccio qui un riassunto.

Ho visto che in molti libri, articoli e altri documenti appare l'espressione "a testo", ma non sono riuscita a trovarla su nessun vocabolario. La mia ipotesi, basata sull'uso che se ne fa nelle occorrenze che ho individuato, è che il significato di tale locuzione sarebbe "nel testo", dove "testo" avrebbe questa accezione riportata dal *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*:

> ciascun esemplare, manoscritto o a stampa, di una medesima opera

Cioè, l'espressione farebbe riferimento allo specifico contenuto scritto di una certa opera letteraria che si trova o si troverà in un determinato manoscritto o in una certa edizione a stampa (coincidente o meno che sia con l'originale dell'opera).

È veramente così?

---

Nelle note all'edizione BUR del *Decameron*, curata da Amedeo Quondam, Maurizio Fiorilla e Giancarlo Alfano, appare spesso l'espressione "a testo". Eccone qualche esempio:

> *commendare*: un verbo molto usato a testo in questo senso

> dopo I 16 sarà usato sempre e solo in questa forma a testo, perché è quella con cui il personaggio è conosciuto ovunque

> *marchese di Monferrato*: Corrado degli Aleramici (1140-1192), che era già in Terrasanta in crociata (non si hanno però notizie storiche di questa moglie, peraltro innominata a testo, che lascia in Monferrato: una prima novella “mista”, di storia e di invenzione; un altro marchesato in questa area è quello di Saluzzo: X 10)

> *Bruggia*: Bruges o Brugge era un importante centro commerciale nelle Fiandre, sulla strada che dall’Inghilterra portava in Italia (solo qui a testo)

> *addivenne che*: la solita clausola di scansione del racconto (con rara variante a testo nella forma del verbo)

> *Maiolica*: ‘quando erano non molto sopra Maiorca’ (la principale isola delle Baleari: la tempesta li ha portati di molto fuori rotta; a testo solo in questa novella)

> *ragazzo*: ‘servo di stalla’ (tutte le sue occorrenze a testo sono in questa sola novella)

> ...

Potreste spiegare cosa significa? Ho cercato alla voce "testo" di parecchi dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovarla. Non si tratta di una locuzione comune? Il significato potrebbe essere "nel testo", facendo riferimento alla specifica opera letteraria (in questo caso il *Decameron*)?

**Aggiornamento:**

Dopo aver posto la domanda, mi sono accorta che Anna Maria Chiavacci Leonardi l'usa anche nei suoi commenti alla *Commedia* (edita da Mondadori). Eccone alcune occorrenze:

> La stragrande maggioranza dei manoscritti legge *ad ira*, che appare a prima vista lezione più logica e chiara; ma proprio per questa maggior facilità e scontatezza (secondo il criterio della *lectio difficilior*), e più per l’autorevole e recisa dichiarazione di Pietro di Dante («non dicas *ad iram*, ut multi textus dicunt falso, sed dicas *ad ire*, idest ad iter»), tale lezione è stata scartata, già nell’edizione del ’21. A sostenere la lezione a testo le più valide ragioni restano ancora quelle del Foscolo: «le voci irate de’ dannati occorsero tanto fin qui che oggimai si sottintendono sempre… ma più ch’altro l’idea di riconoscere al suono della voce che taluno gridi correndo e parmi vera in natura e nuova in poesia, e tanto più efficace quanto ti desta a immaginare lo stupore e l’affanno dell’uomo corrente» (*Commento*, p. 126).

> Per questo preferiamo la punteggiatura a testo, proposta e sostenuta dal D’Ovidio (*Studi danteschi* II, pp. 93-100) e accolta da Sapegno e da Mattalia.

> La tradizione manoscritta dell’antica vulgata presenta in forma maggioritaria la lezione adottata dal Petrocchi (*e spirito*), che la promuove a testo anche in ragione del suo «efficace valore rafforzativo».

> ...

Anche nelle note all'[edizione critica a cura di E. Tonello e P. Trovato del canto XXVII dell'*Inferno*](https://www.academia.edu/43269793/Dante_Inferno_XXVII_edizione_critica_a_cura_di_E_Tonello_e_P_Trovato_con_la_collab_di_M_Cita_F_Marchetti_E_Niccolai_Padova_libreriauniversitaria_it_2020_fuori_commercio) ho trovato:

> non occorre dire che *cheta* è un fiorentinismo, mentre la forma latineggiante *queta* (a testo in Petrocchi) è attestata anche in umbro, romanesco, trevigiano e veneziano.

Un altro esempio si può leggere nell'articolo ["Filologia" di Gianfranco Contini sull'Enciclopedia Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/filologia_%28Enciclopedia-del-Novecento%29/), nella parte intitolata "Il testo nel tempo" della sezione "2. Critica testuale" (grassetto mio):

> La filologia, quando ne ha i mezzi, riapre questo testo chiuso e statico, lo fa aperto e dinamico, lo ripropone nel tempo. La riapertura si opera in direzioni opposte, dopo e prima del testo. La determinazione di quella che si prende per norma, cioè la redazione ultima, non è priva di difficoltà. Per rendersi conto di questa frequente aporia basterà rifarsi all'esperienza autobiografica di qualsiasi produttore di letteratura. Un medesimo manoscritto, o più verosimilmente dattiloscritto, venga usufruito in più occasioni similari, anche abbastanza ravvicinate, e la lezione sottoposta a lievi correzioni migliorative ogni volta in bozze senza che ne sia tenuto registro: correzioni, in pratica, dimenticate. Se di tali pagine l'interessato vorrà finalmente dare un testo definitivo, posto che pure si conceda per finire quello scrupolo che meglio si eroga altrui, si può tenere per certo che, poiché l'acuzie correttoria è discontinua, egli sceglierà, indipendentemente dal livello, le variazioni più approfondenti, senza inibirsene di nuove oltre questa mobile cresta. Un editore ‛terzo' non potrà certo seguire una tale procedura, ma, quando il miglioramento non sia documentariamente univoco, meglio lo rifugerà tutto in apparato, distinguendo le sedi (anche se riuscisse a individuare l'esemplare letteralmente licenziato alla data più bassa). Qualcosa di simile avviene quando qualche implacabile correttore di se stesso lascia suggerimenti su più copie di una sua stampa, oppure, anche se su una copia sola, ne lascia alcuni di stabili, altri di eventuali - come quelli dai medievali contrassegnati mediante *al(iter)* -, altri di alternativi pur non sussistendo dubbi sulla condanna dell'elemento da surrogare. Solo la porzione certa potrà essere ospitata **a testo**, pur dovendosi annotare (meglio se sinotticamente) ogni altra proposta più instabile, e specialmente le certezze negative che meriterebbero, se proprio la modalità della pubblicazione (che offra o simuli una resa compatta) non la renda esosa, un'apposita connotazione tipografica (altro carattere o corpo).

E, nella parte intitolata "Riduzione nell'attestazione plurima" dello stesso articolo si trova (grassetto sempre mio):

> Così ha fatto sistematicamente E. Langlois per la sua eccellente edizione del *Roman de la Rose*, l'opera del Medioevo volgare più diffusa dopo la *Commedia* (non si scordi che ai suoi tempi i viaggi erano ben più onerosi, e l'area va dalla California a Leningrado, da Stoccolma alla Città del Capo, né erano stati ancora inventati i microfilms); del resto sondaggi effettuati nell'ampia sfera da lui trascurata, di codici più tardi del Trecento e di stampe incunabule o cinquecentesche, hanno rivelato una situazione molto interessante per quanto spetta alla storia della tradizione, e anche materiale, assente dall'apparato del Langlois, rinviabile al Duecento, ma nulla suscettibile di salire **a testo**.

Anche nella parte di titolo "Arte allusiva" se ne trova un'occorrenza:

> Nocciolo della comunicazione del Pasquali sono, sulle tracce degli antichi commentatori e dei più raffinati moderni (E. Norden), passi virgiliani che acquistano tutto il loro sapore quando traspaia la filigrana di Vario o di Ennio o di Varrone Atacino; una bell'aggiunta recente (G. B. Conte, *Memoria dei poeti e arte allusiva*, ora in *Memoria dei poeti e sistema letterario*, Torino 1974) fa scorgere Catullo dietro Virgilio entro un contesto emulativo omerico. In casi estremi, cioè in centoni dichiarati, quali ebbero cari la tarda antichità e l'Alto Medioevo, soprattutto attorno a Omero e a Virgilio, un apparato è tenuto a identificare gli ingredienti; ma anche di arte allusiva vi è un settore che giunge addirittura a essere segnalabile **a testo**, se il verso bucolico ‟*Perdita nec serae meminit decedere nocti*" è virgolettabile come, per indicazione di Macrobio, desunto da Vario, o, si può aggiungere, nella canzone petrarchesca *Lasso me* deve subire questo trattamento ogni verso finale di stanza come *incipit* di altrettante canzoni (Arnaut Daniel o chi per esso, Cavalcanti, Dante ecc.).

Quindi, come suggerito da @DaG nel suo commento, la locuzione farebbe riferimento alla scelta particolare del testo fatta dai curatori di una certa opera letteraria (basandosi su determinati criteri)? Si tratterebbe dunque di un'espressione appartenente al linguaggio tecnico proprio dell'editoria critica di opere appartenenti alla storia della letteratura?

L'espressione farebbe riferimento all'accezione numero 7 della voce ["testo" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00001014.jpg), più concretamente a questo?

> ciascun  esemplare, manoscritto  o  a  stampa,  di  una  medesima  opera

"A testo" vorrebbe dire "nel testo" in cui "testo" avrebbe il significato sopra citato? Cioè, farebbe riferimento al contenuto specifico dello scritto di una certa opera letteraria che si trova in un determinato manoscritto o di una certa edizione a stampa?

Se fosse così, quando esistono diversi manoscritti (originali o meno) oppure parecchi dattiloscritti originali di una stessa opera letteraria, si dovrebbe poter dire qualcosa come "a testo nel codice A, anche se tale curatore dell'opera non l'ha messo a testo perché si è basato nel codice B". Per esempio, ho trovato nell'articolo ["Diffusione e studio del nuovo Plauto: esempi di varianti umanistiche nei *Menaechmi*](https://dionysusexmachina.it/dionysus2018/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Tontini_DEF.pdf), di Alba Tontini, questo (il grassetto è sempre mio):

> Il primo ad avere come variante *olfacta*, per la precisione *olfata* – a seguito di un improbabile, non altrimenti attestato, *dic facta* di mano del copista stesso, su *di facta* di prima mano – è H e con lui il Vat. lat. 1632; anche il Pontano e il Laur. 36.46, come si diceva pressoché coevi, lo danno a margine sempre preceduto da *aɫ*. Lo si trova invece già **a testo** nel codice di Giovanni Andrea Bussi, Vat. lat. 11.46948, e in altri codici del II
> gruppo, Ott. 2028, Vitt. Em. II 36549, nel Laur. 36.41 fra i fiorentini, e in tardi rappresentanti della famiglia napoletana quali F, Bon. 2282, Barb. lat. 153, Urb. lat. 343. La lezione, pur non trattandosi di un restauro difficile dato il contesto, ha fatto
> comunque fatica ad affermarsi subito e con decisione.

Anche se è così dovrei poter dire, tenendo conto di  [quanto spiegato in questa domanda e le rispettive risposte](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10494/)

> Nell'edizione con ISBN 9788858409596 della *Luna e i falò* si aveva messo erroneamente **a testo** "in carnicino" dove Pavese aveva scritto "in camicino".

Ecco un esempio simile che ho trovato sull'articolo ["Tra etica del dono e accumulazione"](https://webs.ucm.es/info/italiano/acd/tenzone/biblioteca/doglia/enrico.pdf), di Enrico Fenzi:

> La citazione riguarda il sirventese *Mot era dous e plazens*, n. LXXII nella recente ed. Sharman (Giraut 1989: 460-464) (Pillet-Carstens, 242, 23; Kolsen LXIV: erroneamente **a testo** LXII, che ho corretto).

Anche nell'articolo ["Brancati e la «dittatura clericale»"](http://www.editricesapienza.it/sites/default/files/6051_Vol_OA_Contesti%2520forme%2520e%2520riflessi%2520della%2520censura_0.pdf)
si legge:

> Sebbene gli argomenti attinenti alla sfera sessuale trovassero sempre
> «il partito [democristiano], e dunque la sua censura, pronto a scattare»,
> nel passaggio dal primo al secondo nulla osta, i censori decisero di mantenere **a testo** tutti i riferimenti erotici che in un primo momento erano
> stati segnalati perché considerati osceni. Solamente le espressioni più
> crude vennero modificate. Ad esempio, nella scena finale del secondo atto, viene letta una lettera che rivela che il Commendatore Peppino
> Lauria, pio e devoto esponente della Dc, aveva intrattenuto una relazione adulterina con la cognata sessantenne. Il passo venne interamente
> tagliato, per poi essere ripristinato a condizione che venisse modificata solo l’ultima battuta: «Io vorrei sapere i particolari di come reagisce una vecchia…» venne sostituito dal più casto e generico «Io vorrei sapere come ti comportasti».

Quindi, sembra che si possa dire che, a causa della censura, qualcuno avesse messo "a testo" deliberatamente qualcosa di diverso dall'originale scritto da Brancati.

È così?

Comment: Direi che sia la tua ultima ipotesi, ma spesso, più specificamente, con riferimento al testo messo a punto per quell'edizione (contrapposto alle varianti presenti magari in qualche manoscritto, ma non accolte dal curatore). Se cerchi su Google «"a testo" filologia» trovi molte occorrenze, anche in qualche glossario e simili.

Comment: Ah, grazie, @DaG: avevo ricercato "a testo" senza "filologia" e non avevo trovato nulla di rilevante.

Comment: Ah, ecco, @DaG! Ne ho trovato alcune nelle note alla *Commedia* di Anna Maria Chiavacci Leonardi. Dopo ne riporterò qualcuna nel corpo della domanda.

Comment: Mi sembra di capire che, in un'edizione critica, "a testo" si riferisca a tutto ciò che è inserito nel corpo dell'opera originale, per distinguerlo da tutto quanto costituisce invece la critica/analisi dell'opera (ad esempio, l'apparato critico a pie' di pagina, note a margine, grafie e traduzioni alternative, etc.). Ho trovato qualcosa su [wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edizione_critica) e su questo PDF dell'[Università di Napoli Federico II](https://www.docenti.unina.it/webdocenti-be/allegati/materiale-didattico/669812): non c'è una definizione esplicita di "a testo" ma è intuibile

Comment: @secan: Se ho capito bene ciò che appare nel glossario dell'Università di Napoli che hai linkato, questo sarebbe la "lezione originale". Da quello che si legge alla voce "lezione" di tale glossario («*lezione critica* è quella 
proposta a testo, al termine della *recensio, cioè ipotizzata come originale»), direi che si usi più nel senso menzionato da DaG nel suo commento, ma ovviamente quando parliamo di "testo" ci riferiamo a quello scritto dall'autore dell'opera e non alle note o i commenti scritti dai curatori.

Comment: @DaG: Purtroppo, non sono riuscita a trovare nessuna fonte che spieghi il significato dell'espressione "a testo", ma ho visto un'accezione di "testo" sul GDLI che penso sia precisamente quella a cui questa locuzione farebbe riferimento (vedi i miei ultimi aggiornamenti). Siccome il post con tutti gli aggiornamenti è diventato molto lungo, cercherò di aggiungere un riassunto più tardi.

Answer (score 1):

Nel documento ["L'edizione critica del testo letterario"](https://www.docenti.unina.it/webdocenti-be/allegati/materiale-didattico/669812) già citato da @secan, l'espressione "a testo" è ripetuta circa 15 volte ed è sempre associata alla lezione ipotizzata come originale. I termini che si ripetono sono:

- lezione a testo
- lezione accolta a testo
- lezione da mettere a testo
- lezione proposta a testo

Viene data una definizione che indirettamente chiarisce il significato del termine "a testo":

CONSTITUTIO TEXTUS: in latino, la ‘costituzione del testo’ ossia il procedimento con cui, fra le varie alternative che sono disponibili nella *tradizione, si  ipotizza quale fosse la *lezione originaria e conseguentemente si stabilisce cosa  mettere a testo (AVALLE, p. 95). Nell’uso terminologico, può sovrapporsi in parte a *examinatio e *emendatio, che riguardano  anch’essi la fase decisionale della restituzione.

Allego la pagina citata di Avalle nella quale noterete l'uso dei termini corrispondenti "il testo" e "del testo".

[image]

Una definizione più generica per "testo", applicabile a tutti i casi citati da OP, è quella della [Enciclopedia on line Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/testo/#:%7E:text=testo%20Il%20contenuto%20di%20uno,a%20cui%20ci%20si%20riferisce.):

> Il contenuto di uno scritto o di uno stampato, ossia l’insieme delle parole che lo compongono, considerate non solo nel loro significato ma anche nella forma precisa con cui si leggono nel manoscritto o nell’edizione a cui ci si riferisce. Con valore restrittivo, il corpo originale di uno scritto, distinto da tutto ciò che nella stampa viene inserito o aggiunto (a introduzione, illustrazione, spiegazione, traduzione ecc.).

Si noti nella definizione l'uso della stessa preposizione "a" (con valore di complemento predicativo) a indicare ciò che nella stampa viene inserito o aggiunto **a** introduzione, illustrazione, spiegazione, traduzione, ecc., distinto da quanto riportato a testo.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Va bene, @Giuseppe: nel documento che hai linkato, "a testo" è sempre associato alla lezione ipotizzata come originale, ma non lo è nell'ultimo esempio che ho appena riportato nel mio aggiornamento al corpo della domanda, in cui questa espressione fa riferimento a un refuso. Quindi, "a testo" non significherebbe "nel testo dell'opera ipotizzato come originale", come mi sembra di capire in questa tua risposta. La questione continua, dunque, aperta.

Comment: L'esempio su Brancati che ho appena aggiunto sembra confermare ciò che ho detto nel mio commento precedente.

Comment: Ma allora questa risposta non è completa: potresti completarla, per favore?

Comment: Suggerimenti su come migliorare la risposta?